# sed - insert text after other text

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting, command

So I have this line:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var
```

and I need to insert 'index.php' using **sed** command after **DirectoryIndex** (I don't want to replace it, only insert 'index.php') so that looks like this one:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.html.var
```

Comment: This should be _really_ trivial.  Did you make _any_ attempt whatsoever?

Comment: While I assume that someone would readily toss solutions in front of you, I'd highly recommend reading the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting some text into a line relative to a particular substring involves replacing the substring with itself + the new text:

```
sed 's/DirectoryIndex/& index.php/'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's/(DirectoryIndex)/\1 index.php/' file.txt
```